# Why Isn't Shadow Working On IOS With Expo?

Tags: css, expo, react-native-ios, shadow

The code for the component is:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.tab}></View>
</View>
```

The styling is:

```
const vw = Dimensions.get("window").width/100
const vh = Dimensions.get("window").height/100

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        position:"relative",
        width:25*vw,
        height:25*vw,
        zIndex:1000
    },
    tab:{
        position:"absolute",
        top:3.5*vw,
        bottom:3.5*vw,
        left:3.5*vw,
        right:3.5*vw,
        backgroundColor:"red",
        shadowColor:"green",
        shadowOffset:{
            width:-10,
            height:-10
        }
    },
})
```

When I run it on the web, it is fine, and the shadow shows up
When I run it on an IOS simulator or my iPhone no shadow shows up

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a shadow library for react native. It's called **shadows-rn** and if you need transparency, layered shadows, or inset shadows its a good solution.

For the above question, you must include the **shadowRadius** and the **shadowOpacity**

[shadows-rn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shadows-rn)